# Prometheus can't find api services running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have deployed Prometheus to a running kubernetes cluster.
I want it to use service discovery to find all our services and scrape their health endpoint to collect their metrics.
The problem is that even though it finds the services using the scrape config `kubernetes-apiservers` it says all services are down.
I don't need an absolute solution to the problem even suggestions on how I might debug this would be very helpful.

Within my config I have

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: https
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: default;kubernetes;https
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: apiserver
    action: replace
```

when I look on the service discovery tab it says that only 1 of 43 kubernetes-apiservers are available.  [image]

On the page status -> targets everything seems to be up.
Any guess as to where I can see why the 42 other services aren't being scraped.

[image]

Comment: If you open *Status->Targets* you'll be able to see why they're down (there has to be an error message for each). Please add one to the question.

Comment: @anemyte I've included a screenshot of that page. 
Everything seems to be up on that page.

Comment: So they are not down, they're just dropped. It is either the first relabeling that drops them (it's just the only thing in the configuration snippet that can drop targets) or something that you decided not to show here.

Comment: @anemyte what do you mean by the first relabelling that drops them? 
Are you saying it might not be scraping my endpoints because of some config in the relabelling?

Comment: I removed the relabelling section, restarted prometheus and its still not scraping my services.
Any other ideas how I might debug this?

Comment: Confirm whether the configuration you showed is actually being used. As I said, without that relabeling point with `action: keep`, there is nothing more that can drop targets.